# Authentification with salt

Tags: java, authentication, salt, sha

i'm trying to write a sign in activity , i wrote the `hashPassword` function below. Why does it give a different result for the same salt and password?

```
  import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;

import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        System.out.println("Hello World!");
       try { System.out.println("test1: "+hashPassword("[B@2b1e4124","bfnfnfjfjf"));
           System.out.println("test2: "+hashPassword("[B@2b1e4124","bfnfnfjfjf"));}
       catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException e){}

    }
     public static  String hashPassword(String password, String salt) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {

        char[] passwordChars = password.toCharArray();
        byte[] saltBytes =salt.getBytes();
        PBEKeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(
                passwordChars,
                saltBytes,
                5000,
                10
        );
        SecretKeyFactory key = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA512");
        byte[] hashedPassword = key.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded();
        return hashedPassword.toString();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your hash is actually calculating the same result each time, but you're calling `toString` on the resulting byte array. This returns a debug string, which is different for each instance (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140402/how-do-i-print-my-java-object-without-getting-sometype2f92e0f4) for details).

Instead of

```
return hashedPassword.toString();
```

You should

```
return hashedPassword;
```

... and use the `byte[]` directly.

If you want to display the hash in a human readable format, you could print it like this:

```
String hashString = new BigInteger(1, hashedPassword).toString(16);
System.out.println(hashString);
```

There is a second mistake in your code. The forth argument to the `PBEKeySpec` constructor is the length in *bits*. 10 is way too short to be useful. You probably want 512 (the SHA512 output length).